# web page in C++ desktop application

Tags: c++, web-applications, desktop-application, c++builder

I have a Borland C++ application and I am new to desktop applications.

I would like in one of the pages to embed a web page of another application of mine that the URL is something like:

www.mysite.com/thepage

In HTML I can use `<IFrame>`. How can I do it in Borland C++?

Comment: Strange to hear "n HTML I can use . How can I do it in Borland C++?" :)

Comment: @NDeveloper - I added the iframe tag that disappeared before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VCL in Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero C++Builder has a native TCppWebBrowser component that is a wrapper for the Internet Explorer ActiveX control.  Or you can [embed the control manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752044(VS.85).aspx).  If you do not want to rely on Internet Explorer, FireFox has a similar control available, IIRC.  Or there are third-party VCL web browser components available, such as [PBear](http://pbear.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you never to compare HTML with C++. They are **extremely**, **totally** , **completely** different and can't be compared.

Also I would not call anything in C++ desktop application as **Page**.

As for displaying HTML content use any HTML/Web Browser control.

Comment: How would you call it instead of a Page?

Comment: It depends from your application. Most commonly you will call it window or dialog. Seems you have a web background that is why.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Borland C++ for Windows or at C Builder you should be able to embed a HTML control in a application window. Here you can find the implementation of a custom HTML control in plain C: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/cwebpage.aspx . 
There is also a web control from Microsoft. You can find out more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
Good Luck!

Comment: WebBrowser Control in the second link you have provided will not work as in question is said that Borland C++ is used. And the one you have gave is for .NET.

Comment: That control is a wrapper over the Microsoft ActiveX control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085%28v=VS.85%29.aspx